# How can I add width and height to each img tag in string?

Tags: jquery

I have a string containing both text and multiple IMG tags, but I have to add the attribute `width="20"` and `height="20"` to each of these IMG tags.

The script that adds the IMG tags to the initial string is `value = emojione.toImage(value)` and I have tried different variations of adding the `width="20"` and `height="20"`to IMG tags in the string, but my last try was:

```
value = $(value).foreach(img).attr("width", "20");
value = $(value).foreach(img).attr("height", "20")
```

**For a better understanding, here is my script:**

```
$("#UserSpecificMessageText").change(function () { //INPUT FIELD # 1 //
  var value = $(this).val();
  value = emojione.toImage(value);

  // HERE I NEED TO ADD WIDTH AND HEIGHT //

                                          
  $("#UserSpecificMessageTextToEmail").val(value); // ANOTHER INPUT FIELD
});
```

None of the solutions I have been able to find here and on google works .. how can I make this work? :-)

**NOTE!** *Unfortunately it is not an option to use CSS class, that I tried at first, but the string is used in a HTML mail that should be displayed in Outlook; and `img.emojione {width: 20px !important; height: 20px !important;}` have no effect on the html in the string.*

**Example of string:**

```
<img class="emojione" title=":wink:" src="[URL]"/> Some text <img class="emojione" title=":relieved:" src="[URL]"/> Some other text <img class="emojione" title=":rofl:" src="[URL]"/>
```

Comment: I'm close-voting this because [the OP is *actually* having issues with `[object object]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70384733/2430549), but the question has no details about objects at all, nor are objects mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to even loop over the images with jQuery, try this

```js
$(value).find(img).attr("width", "20").attr("height", "20");
```

Or

```js
$(value).find(img).width(20).height(20);
```

I assume that `value` is some sort of CSS selector or raw HTML string?

Also please note that if this is for an email, you won't be able to run any JS scripts, let alone bring in library like jQuery. I assume you are doing some sort of pre processing for email templates?

Comment: Hi @Ceebs .. The `value` is the "Example of String " in my post .. I have also just added a section "For a better understanding, here is my script" in the post so you might get a clearer understanding of the issue :-)

Comment: Another good, working answer! @StigKølbæk See, it's very simple to change image heights and widths, there are so many solutions by many users.  BTW _"here is my script... so you might get a clearer understanding..."_  Having a script is nice, but explaining what you need might be more helpful.

Comment: Upvoted!  Thanks for posting a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach()` is a Higher Order Function in Javascript. It's equivalent function in JQuery is `each()`. So `img` is used wrongly. Use a callback within `foreach()`.

Something like this:

```
$(value).each(img =>{
   img.attr("width", "20");
   img.attr("height","20");
});
```

**Note:** I am assuming your `value` object is returning an array of images

Answer (score -1):

***`foreach()` is not a function.***

You might be thinking of [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in JavaScript or [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) in jQuery.  Here is a working solution using jQuery, since you have this question tagged as `jQuery()`...

```js
$("#resize").on('click', function(e) {
    img = $('.img');
    value = $('.img').each(function(index) {
       $(this).attr('width', '50px');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="resize">Resize</button><br>

<img class="img" width="200" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/Bogolyubovo_asv2019-01_img02_Intercession_Church.jpg/1000px-Bogolyubovo_asv2019-01_img02_Intercession_Church.jpg">
```

Comment: Hi @HoldOffHunger .. This seems to be doing what I need, although I have big difficulties to convert the `[object object]` back to a string again .. I have tried outerHTML and toString in different variations, but no matter what  it remains `[object object]` .. any thoughts on how to fix this? :-)

Comment: Hey, @StigKølbæk, glad this answer helped you with your issue!  I'd like to help you with your JSON-object parsing, but I don't see any code for that.  Maybe that's a good thing for a new question?  That way, problems can be separated, and people definitely with an image-setting problem will find a concise answer preferable.

Comment: Hi @HoldOffHunger .. Thats the thing, there is no JSON object in this part, thats what I get as an outcome of your script, and not the string I parsed, so my issue is not quite 1fixed yet :-) .. What I meant was that it seems your script does something, I just need to get the HTML in the Object that your script makes

Comment: @StigKølbæk Not sure what you mean.  My demo above works, doesn't it?  It sounds like you have a completely different problem than adjusting width and height of your img tags, as your question title states.

Comment: No, I need to add height and width to IMG tags, tags that are added to  `value` using `value = emojione.toImage(value);` before I need to add the width and height, the output of `value = emojione.toImage(value);` is what I have under "Example of string:" .. but when I run value through your script I no longer have ´<img class="emojione" title=":wink:" src="[URL]"/> Some text ....´ but only `[object object]` .. please take a look at the part in my post called  ´For a better understanding, here is my script:´

Comment: Hey @StigKølbæk; Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  Also, please take a look at [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), i.e.: _"Your questions should be reasonably scoped."_  We have more than a page of back and forth on this "object" problem (which is not in the title, or mentioned in the question at all), and I still am not sure what you're saying.

Comment: Hey @HoldOffHunger.. I am sorry if my post does not clarify what I am doing, I would say that from my pov the script should explain itself, but I must be wrong.. to clarify: I have an input with an emoji picker, this contains text and emojis in form of i.e. `:rofl:`  .. the value from the input I "run through" `emojione.toImage(value)` that transforms the inline emoji code (i.e. `:rofl:`) into `<img class="emojione" title=":rofl:" src="[URL]"/>`  meaning all emojis in the text are made to images .. it is these IMG tags I need to add width/height,  before posting to e-mail script.

Comment: Hey, @StigKølbæk : That has nothing to do with _"How can I add width and height to each img tag in string?"_  Please review those links on how to ask a question, thank you.